# Read-only file system error in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, mount, nfs

I am getting an error while adding NFS in the Kubernetes cluster. I was able to mount the NFS but not able to add a file or directory in the mount location.

This is my yaml file

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pod-using-nfs
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: nfs-volume
      nfs:
        server: 10.01.26.81
        path: /nfs_data/nfs_share_home_test/testuser
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: alpine
      volumeMounts:
        - name: nfs-volume
          mountPath: /home/kube/testuser
```

Then I ran the following commands for building the pod

```
kubectl apply -f session.yaml
kubectl exec -it pod-using-nfs sh
```

After I exec to the pod,

```
/ # cd home/kube/testuser/
/home/kube/testuser# touch hello
touch: hello: Read-only file system
```

Expected output is

```
/ # cd home/kube/testuser/
/home/kube/testuser# touch hello
/home/kube/testuser# ls
hello
```

Should I need to add any securityContext to the yaml for fixing this?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you try mounting this NFS to some linux node directly and try if it works? Is it self-hosted NFS server? If so, is configuration valid and allows for write operation?

Comment: @HelloWorld That fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I am very happy to hear it. Can you describe what you have changed, post it as the answer and mark as accepted?

Comment: I created a different nfs server. And changed permission in exports file again. That fixed the issue. I'm new to stack over flow account. And I've upvoted your answer. Anything else to do?

Comment: I was hoping maybe you could provide example with working configuration for community facing this very problem.